# Будет ли запрос работать и как добавить идентификатор

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

```
(SELECT * FROM `user`)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM `list`)
where `last_inf` IS NOT NULL
```

Собственно будет ли данный запрос работать, необходимо из 2 таблиц выбрать все записи поле last_inf которых содержит хоть что та.

Второй вопрос, каким образом возможно добавить к записям какой нибудь идентификатор для того чтобы в цикле понять какая запись от какой таблицы...

Comment: "выбрать все записи" --- а все колонки совпадают по именам и количеству?

Comment: Не по именам не по количеству. Что делать, отдельно писать каждый запрос и под каждый запрос цикл? Необходимо вытащить все записи из 3 таблиц, в каждой таблице есть поле last_inf, которое не должно быть пустым.

Comment: Почему нельзя сделать просто выборку из двух таблиц без UNION? Какая-то ошибка архитектуры тут. Что это за мистический last_inf в двух никак не связанных с собой таблицах.

Comment: То есть придется делать запрос и цикл, для 3 таблиц отдельно? Необходимо просто из трех 3 таблиц выбрать записи по одному полю. Зачем писать 3 запрос и 3 цикла, когда если это возможно. Выполнить все в одном....

Comment: видимо потому что выбрать разные сущьности одним запросом - нельзя.

Comment: Так по одному полю или все? Звёздочка - это все колонки из таблицы.... В общем, задача тут не описана в полной мере, тут у тебя скорее хотелка........ В лучше случае было бы нормально привести структуру таблиц......сказать их предназначение, сказать что за колонка last_inf и за что отвечает........ сказать что не "выбрать ВСЕ записи", а "выбрать у каждой таблицы по конкретной колонке (ЕЁ ИМЯ) и объединить их"  ............. ЗЫ: откуда взялись три таблицы вместо двух?

Comment: Где 3 там и пять будет) Я просто хочу одним спросом вытащить все записи из 3-5 таблиц, вытащить те записи у которых поле last_inf не пустое. Да, необходимо вытащить содержимое всех полей для каждой записи, количество их разница в каждой таблице. Эти таблицы никак с между собой не связаны...

Comment: Понятно. Тогда это скорее бессмысленная задача, либо, как я уже отметил - ошибка проектирования.  Либо ошибка самой задачи (вытаскивать из 3-5-7-8 таблиц с совершенно разным количеством столбцов через union никто не будет) и нужно лучше понять что нужно и зачем доставать все эти данные таким образом

Comment: В худшем случае да, лучше сделать три запроса и три цикла, В лучшем - больше проанализировать задачу и понять что конкретно нужно.. Но явно не это

Comment: Кстати, один запрос не всегда быстрее трёх отдельных. Это доказано. (Вчера на работе кстати тоже с этим столкнулся, что один запрос со вложенным работает дольше, чем два оных поотдельности)

Answer (score 1):

1. Ваш запрос будет работать если все колонки из таблиц `user` и `list` совпадают по именам и количеству. Но колонка `last_inf` будет не пустая ТОЛЬКО в таблице `list`.
2. Идентификатор таблицы можно добавить в `SELECT`

В результате получиться:

```
SELECT *, 'user' as Discriminator FROM `user`
where `last_inf` IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT *, 'list' as Discriminator FROM `list`
where `last_inf` IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: для mysql union не требует совпадения имен, только количества полей

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков как и в MS SQL. Только помимо количества, ещё поля должны быть однотипные и этот момент лучше держать на контроле, т.к. может быть некорректное приведения типов

Comment: @VitaliyZlobin Само собой про приведение типов помнить нужно, я просто уточнил что имена полей не важны :) тогда уж и в pgsql так же если вдаваться в подробности и еще в куче диалектов :)